# PHP OOP Update Protected String on Extended Class __construct

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to create my first PHP class and have been stuck on how to update protected strings.

What i'm trying to do is create an extended class that works with protected strings from the main class.

I'm able to update the string when the first class loads, but when I load my extended class it does not show the updated text.

What am I doing wrong?

```
class test {
    protected $testing = 'test';

    function __construct(){
        echo "The Test class has loaded (".$this->testing.")";
        $this->testing='changed';
        echo "Updated to (".$this->testing.")";
    }
}

class test2 EXTENDS test {

    function __construct(){
        echo "The Test2 class has loaded (".$this->testing.")";
        $this->testing='updated';
        echo 'The string has been updated to ('.$this->testing.')';
    }
}

$blah = new test();
$blah2 = new test2();
```

The results i'm trying to get are:

The Test class has loaded (test)
Updated to (changed)

The Test2 class has loaded (changed)
The string has been updated to (updated)

Comment: After running the code everything seems fine, what were you expecting to happen? The correct message is output:`The string has been updated to (updated)`

Comment: I'm trying to get the updated string from the first class. I've updated the question with the expected results. Thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects don't affect class state while program continues running which means those two instantiations are apart from each other. However, you can keep the changes to the class instead using `static` properties:

```
class test
{
    protected static $testing = 'test';

    function __construct()
    {
        echo "The Test class has loaded (" . self::$testing . ")";
        self::$testing = 'changed';
        echo "Updated to (" . self::$testing . ")";
    }
}

class test2 extends test
{
    function __construct()
    {
        echo "The Test2 class has loaded (" . self::$testing . ")";
        self::$testing = 'updated';
        echo 'The string has been updated to (' . self::$testing . ')';
    }
}

$blah = new test();
echo PHP_EOL;
$blah2 = new test2();
```

Output:

```
The Test class has loaded (test)Updated to (changed)
The Test2 class has loaded (changed)The string has been updated to (updated)
```

Comment: Thought it would be helpful to point out that if you were to initialize `test2` before `test` the output would be: `The Test2 class has loaded (test)The string has been updated to (updated)
The Test class has loaded (updated)Updated to (changed)`. Static properties can be extremely helpful when used correctly but can also yield confusing results misused.

Answer (score 5):

You need to construct the parent. Just because a child class extends a parent class, doesn't mean that the parent class automatically is created/constructed when the child class is. It just inherits the functionality (properties / methods).

You can do this with: `parent::__construct();`

I made a few small edits to your source, notably [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) styled class names and line breaks. But everything else is the same.

```
<?php

class Test {
    protected $testing = 'original';

    function __construct(){
        echo "The Test class has loaded (".$this->testing.")\n";
        $this->testing = 'Test';
        echo "Updated to (".$this->testing.")\n";
    }
}

class TestTwo extends test {

    function __construct(){
        echo "Child class TestTwo class has loaded (".$this->testing.")\n";
        parent::__construct();
        echo "Parent class Test class has loaded (".$this->testing.")\n";
        $this->testing = 'TestTwo';
        echo "The string has been updated to (".$this->testing.")\n";
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$testTwo = new TestTwo();
```

Which will give you the following output:

```
The Test class has loaded (original)
Updated to (Test)
Child class TestTwo class has loaded (original)
The Test class has loaded (original)
Updated to (Test)
Parent class Test class has loaded (Test)
The string has been updated to (TestTwo)
```

Comment: Calling the parent::__construct() from the extended class does seem to allow me to access the protected string.. but is there no way to access the protected string in the extended class without doing the __construct() again? That's making the first class __construct run twice and I want to only add my extended classes if they are needed and they will need to access the main class protected strings.

Comment: You can *always* access a protected value in a child class. Also, it doesn't make the construct run twice, it only runs once. It gets called twice because you're instantiating `Test` and then `TestTwo`. It runs once on each, but they have different scopes. Furthermore, You are running `$this->testing = 'Test';` in the constructor of `Test` so the only way to have that line of code run is by instantiating the `Test` (either `new Test` or `parent::__construct`). You might want to put that functionality in a class function in `Test` which would make it available to call in `TestTwo`.